# Detect when a Google maps route is complete using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I'm drawing directions to a map that, due to licensing restraints, I need to chain as several calls. Through the maps API I can detect when a map is finished rendering but this does not include the route being drawn to the map. I want to call a function to show a button when the route is finished being rendered. Here is my code:

```
// render the map from all points in the array
function renderMap() {
    $('.allRunners').hide(); // temp hide the button
    var ds = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var points = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < routeData.length; i++) {
        if (routeData[i].type == "free") {
            processPolyLeg(routeData, i);
        } else {
            processLeg(routeData, i, ds);
        }
    }

    updateUnitMarkers();
    updateDistance();
}
```

I tried using the jQuery deferred object to detect when the renderMap function was done, but I think I am targeting the wrong function as this happens almost immediately.

```
$.when(renderMap()).done(function () {
    $('.allRunners').show();
});
```

I think I need to target the renderLeg function to know when the last time it is called, but this function, as you can see below, has params passed to it that aren't necessarily available when I want to use the deferred object:

```
// when redrawing we need to wrap the asynchronous call to make it plot properly.
function processLeg(routeData, i, ds, retry) {
    // set up the initial request object
    var request = {
        origin: routeData[i].origin,
        destination: routeData[i].destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };

    ds.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            // render the leg and set the renderer
            renderLeg(routeData, i, response);
            if (retry) {
                updateUnitMarkers();
                updateDistance();

            }
        } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                //retry
                processLeg(routeData, i, ds, true);

            }, 200);
        }
    });
}

// renders a leg to the map and updates the reference to the renderer
function renderLeg(routeData, i, response) {
    var dr = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        'draggable': false,
        'map': map,
        'preserveViewport': true,
        'suppressMarkers': true,
        'polylineOptions': { strokeColor: "#368CB9", strokeOpacity: 1, strokeWeight: 4 }
    });

    // render this step of the route to the map
    dr.setDirections(response);
    routeData[i].renderer = dr;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: DirectionsRenderer has a `directions_changed` event. Have you tried binding any code to that?

Comment: @Salman I hadn't, but I'm reading about that now. Thanks for the steer.